Parent tag will be bold, when one of the children have active class
I managed to highlight the parent tag when one of the children is active (thanks to answers from StackOverflow people!) but it highlighted all of the parent tag. I just want to highlight it's own parents


$('.tag').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  updateFilter();
});

function updateFilter() {
  $('.filter').toggleClass('active', $('.tag.active').length > 0);
}
.tag.active {
  color: red;
}

.filter.active {
  color: blue;
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p class="filter">filter</p>
  <div class="tag-wrap">
    <a class="tag">tag 1</a>
    <a class="tag">tag 2</a>  
    <a class="tag">tag 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="wrap">
  <p class="filter">filter 2</p>
  <div class="tag-wrap">
    <a class="tag">tag 1</a>
    <a class="tag">tag 2</a>  
    <a class="tag">tag 3</a>
  </div>
</div>




one way to do it is using .parent() and .siblings(), like,
..
$('.tag').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  updateFilter($(this));
});

function updateFilter($ele) {
  $ele.parent().siblings('.filter').toggleClass('active', $('.tag.active').length > 0);
}
..

